# Loading daemon then jnlp in Windows

Tags: android, windows, batch-file

I'm a Non programmer :: Win XP/Win 7

I want to demonstrate android devices for a SeniorNet group.

I use androidscreencast.jnlp to mirror screen views on a device that are projected for group viewing.

I use a daemon created with adb.exe shell to ensure the .jnlp script recognises the device, pre-set in debug mode.

The demon must be active before the .jnlp script which is invoked.

I wrote two-lines batch file to load the daemon first and then run the script.

The daemon is created OK but the cursor is held in the adb command box.

I had assumed that having completed the action specified in the  first line of the batch file it would then proceed to action the second instruction.

Can someone help me with a DOS or jnlp script that will first create the daemon and then load the screencast?

Comment: Can you show your "two lines" batch file?

Comment: START C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe shell
 START C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\platform-tools\androidscreencast(1).jnlp

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it, your batch file is

```
START C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe shell 
START C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\platform-tools\androidscreenc‌​ast(1).jnlp
```

As is, this code should start in a new window the adb.exe with an interactive shell over the device, and once the adb.exe starts to execute, without waiting, it starts the .jnlp file.

If the adb.exe is used to ensure the device is connected, and it is not needed that the adb keeps running, remove the `START` command from first line (to execute in the same window and wait for command to finish) and change parameter to adb, replacing `shell` with `devices` to detect and list devices connected to the pc. This should be enough to ensure the device is connected.

If you need to keep the adb shell open, but do not need to execute anything on it, add a delay between the two batch file commands to ensure first one completes the start before the second one starts. Use `timeout /t 20` (20 seconds delay) or `ping -n 21 localhost > nul` (20 seconds delay, if you do not have timeout command). Adjust delay as needed.

If you need to execute some kind of command in the adb shell, you have two options

1 - If the adb shell is not needed after command execution on device, change the first line, removing the 'START' (to wait for command completion) and change parameters to adb, instead of start an interactive shell with `shell` command, send directly the needed command with `shell commandToExecute`. This creates the shell, emits the command and exits, so the next line if batch file will execute.

2 - If you need to keep the adb open, leave the first line as is, to allow you to launch the adb in another window to interact with the device, but insert in batch file before the second line (which becomes the third line) a `pause` command. When adb has started and command executed on shell, change active window to the first one, that will be waiting for key press to continue.

Comment: Your suggestions welcomed and after various trials the following script works OK

Comment: START C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe shell

 ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1500 > nul

 START C:\androidscreencast.jnlp